# Upgrade 2013 Kendo MVC to 2018 Kendo MVC. What version to download?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

We currently have a site using an older version of Kendo for MVC (Kendo UI  v2013.2.716).  We need to upgrade it to the latest version of Kendo.

We have downloaded Kendo UI for jQuery 2018.1.221 from our licensed login.  There does not seem to be a Kendo for MVC listed.  When I unzip the files I see thre is not a kendo.mvc.dll to be found.

What is the correct version of Kendo we should now be downloading and using?  Is the kendo.mvc.dll still being used for MVC applications using Ajax calls to the server?

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Off-topic for SO really. Best version is usually the latest but check the release history https://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui/release-history. kendo.mvc.dll is still used so please log back in to your account and look again at the product downloads. You have a license so Telerik support will quickly answer any further questions you have with better guidance than we can give you here with respect to product versions and installation.

Comment: Kendo for MVC is still available and the latest release is 2018.2.516. It is available with the name "Progress® Telerik® UI for ASP.NET MVC".

Comment: Even though it says Telerik in the name?  I saw that and didn't think it was the correct download

Comment: Kendo UI for JQuery does not include the MVC wrapper. You need a licensed copy for that which you download from the Progress Control Panel.